# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll while trying to execute stored procedure from c# code

Tags: c#, mysql, windows-services

Here is a part of my C# windows service code......

```
        int status = 0;

        using (MySqlConnection myconnection = new MySqlConnection(connectionCdrBank))
        {

            try
            {
                myconnection.ConnectionTimeout = 1000;
                myconnection.Open();
                myconnection.BeginTransaction();

                MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand("ClearTempTable", myconnection);
                mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                ***status = mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();***

                MySqlCommand mycommand1 = new MySqlCommand(query, myconnection);
                mycommand1.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                status = mycommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MySqlCommand mycommand2 = new MySqlCommand("InsertToCdrDetailsTempTable", myconnection);
                mycommand2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                mycommand2.CommandTimeout = 1000;
                status = Convert.ToInt32(mycommand2.ExecuteScalar());

                myconnection.Commit();
                myconnection.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error:" + ex.Message);
                if (myconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    myconnection.Rollback();
                status = (ex.Message.IndexOf("Duplicate entry") != -1) ? -1000 : 0;
                swLog.WriteErrorToLog("");
                swLog.WriteErrorToLog("Error while saving: " + ex.Message);
                mail.SentMail("Error while saving:", ex.Message);
                swLog.CloseLogger();
            }
        }
```

while trying to execute the highlighted portion(code in ***) its causes an error 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll and the windows service stops by itself.Any know what it could be all about??
Here is the stack trace

```
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes    
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlCommand.a(System.Data.CommandBehavior A_0 = Default, System.IDisposable A_1 = {Devart.Data.MySql.aw}, int A_2 = 0, int A_3 = 0) + 0x586 bytes  
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior = Default) + 0x14a bytes   
System.Data.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() + 0xd bytes    
Devart.Data.dll!Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteNonQuery() + 0x41 bytes  
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Commit() + 0xa2 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlInternalConnection.Close() + 0x104 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.Close() + 0x52 bytes   
Devart.Data.MySql.dll!Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection.Close() + 0x26 bytes
```

Comment: Ok. Then a stacktrace would be good

Comment: I strongly recommend you allow your service to be run as a console application and debug from there. Once you get a `StackOverflowException` you will be able to get the call stack - (even though it could take up to a minute for VS to grab it for you). A `StackOverflowException` that is thrown by the CLR can never be caught - so you need a debugger attached.

Comment: @JonathanDickinson well i'm not getting it into the catch exception portion while trying to debug...its just stops the service...and the exception is show at that particular line of code not inside the catch portion

Comment: @Jay you should [break on all exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx). As I said - the code in your `catch` block will **never ever** execute, if you get a `StackOverflowException` - the CLR will panic and quit. You might want to [turn off just my code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx) as well. You **must** use a debugger (like Visual Studio) if you are trying to find an exception of this class.

Answer (score 3):

In order to debug this issue you must realise a few things first: under the conditions when a `StackOverflowException` is thrown the CLR is unable to recover and will **not** execute any more of your code (just like an `OutOfMemoryException` and `InvalidProgramException` as far as I remember) - even if your code is in a `catch` block (this means that your logger simply won't log the exception). It will give up and immediately quit **unless** you have an actual debugger attached. You can demonstrate it as follows:

```
static void Main()
{
  try
  {
    StackOverflow();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    // This line will NEVER execute.
    Console.WriteLine("Caught {0}", ex);
  }
}

static void StackOverflow() { StackOverflow(); }
```

In order to find out why the exception is occurring you need to attach with a real debugger (like Visual Studio or MonoDevelop) the minute the application starts. You can do this in a service application by adding your own `public` `Start()` method to the class that implements `ServiceBase`; following this simple call the `Run` on your service instance (instead of `ServiceBase.Run(...)`). This will give you an application that you can 'F5-debug'. As always you can use conditional pragmas (`#IF DEBUG`) to make it compile as a real service in release. You can also place `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Attach()` as the first line in your `Main` method.

Once you have attached you need to reproduce the error. There is a very good chance your debugger will break on one of these exceptions - if it does not you need to 'break on all exceptions' and turn off 'just my code' (or whatever the equivalent is in your IDE of choice).

To re-iterate: your logger **WILL NOT** log the `StackOverflowException`.

Looking at the stack trace I noticed that none of the code is caused by you (they are all Devart method frames) - so we really can't answer this question beyond: contact Devart support and provide them with this information (or even a link to this question). A `StackOverflowException` should quickly make it's way to the top of any competent companies bug log (and they are competent from my experience). Alternatively download and install a new version of the MySQL component and see if that remedies the situation.

Alternatively use ILSpy to debug into their code (which is obfuscated, but I am sure you could make head-and-tails of it) and see what's causing the exception and you might be able to work around it.

Comment: well.. i tried as you said but my debugger is breaking on this exception.

Comment: @Jay great - now get a stack trace from the debugger. Look for a 'Call Stack' window somewhere.

Comment: @Jay right click on external code and choose "Show External Code"

Comment: @Jay - great. I added a two paragraphs into the answer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7467/discussion-between-jay-and-jonathan-dickinson)

Answer (score 0):

The call causing the stack overflow exception is not always the one that keeps recursing. It's just "the straw that breaks the camel's back". Look at the stack trace before that method to find out which call appears repeatedly.